# Error: attempt to read or write outside of partition

Tags: grubrescue

I left the computer as a 3rd night running ddrescue doing a cloning disk to disk.

When i got up this morning just the terminal was running but anything else had dissapeared.... the desktop and bars had dissapeared so i could work or do anything (i dont really now how to you the terminal much i use xwindows for linux mint even to install programs)  . So I closed the terminal and switched off the laptop manually since i knew i could continue ddrescue with the log file!!

I disconnected the 2 disks i had attached and I restarted the computer..... this is what I got

error: attempt to read or write outside of partition 
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

what do I do now? take into the account i do not have another computer and i have a lot information in there since i emptied my new disk to clone the old disk in my laptop..... info that i dont want to loose!!

I have tried this

grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/ #  this is root and bootloader of linux
grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos5)
grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos5

but when I do

Grub rescue> ls /boot         says error: attempt to read or write outside of partition  as well if I do
Grub rescue> ls /home    gives the same error but

I can do fine:
Grub rescue> ls /media      or  ls /root  or ls /lib

I have tried

grub rescue > insmod normal       but it says the sames 
 error: attempt to read or write outside of partition

what can i do??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you copying your **boot partition** to the external disk? It may have enough data on it to boot from it. If you can at least get into a text console you may be able to use `fdisk` to fix your internal disk.

Comment: No I was doing a clone of a external HD to a external HD. The only thing i was creating in my internal HD was the log file. I just get Grub rescue> fdisk does not work there. I don't know how to open a terminal from there